# Questions put on hold and then deleted tell the user to edit the question or comment, neither of which is possible

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Questions put on hold and then deleted tell the user to edit the question or comment, neither of which is possible.

[image: bug]

Comment: This isn't a bug.  It was placed on hold by the community then due to the quality a moderator made a judgment discussion to delete the question.

Comment: IMO this should be treated as a UI bug. The page tells the user to do one thing but disallows them from doing it. The page displays dead links to the user (the edit your question and the leave a comment link). But if you want to say it's not a bug and downvote someone who has taken to point out awful usability issues have at it.

Comment: Most of the time a question that is closed by the community isn't deleted by a moderator.  Close questions are just normally automatically deleted after a period of time.  Are you really upset about a downvote on a meta website?  **On a Meta website a downvote means I don't agree with you.**  Besides considering votes are anonymous you don't even know WHO gave you that downvote.

Comment: Mokubai - this is a completely different question than the one you marked it as a duplicate as. This is a bug report in relation to the usability of the software. The other is a question about what type of question to ask.

Comment: My apologies Ramhound. I thought you had closed the question also marking it as a duplicate, but that was Mokubai. I didn't know the meaning of the downvotes on Meta. I thought they would signify a bad question like the non-Meta sites. Thanks for clearing that up. It seems I can't set a foot right on SE these days!

Comment: Mokubai didn't close the question.  He deleted the question after it was closed by the community.  This isn't personal.  So do yourself a favor don't get upset about downvotes on any sE website.

Comment: I'm referring to this question that was "marked as duplicate by Mokubai". I have a (minor online, won't lose sleep over type) problem with that as it's clearly not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Mokubai (or anyone) - this question is about the dialog on a deleted question instructing the author to edit or comment when it appears that this is not possible.  Can someone address how to accomplish either task or confirm that it is not possible (in which case the dialog should probably be clarified)?

Comment: @fixer1234 - Most closed questions are not deleted by moderators.  Most of the time a question is either closed ( or placed on hold ) or its deleted by a moderator.  The question was placed on hold but then was deleted, the fact it was deleted, means the question isn't or shouldn't be improved upon by the author until its undeleted.

Comment: @Ramhound - Isn't that sort of a catch-22?  It requires revision in order to get undeleted but you can't revise it until it's undeleted?  My point is really about the instructions provided to the author by the system when a question is deleted.  If it can't be revised while deleted, the instructions shouldn't say to do that.  If it can be revised, there needs to be instructions on how to access it and do that.  My point isn't about this particular question, but the process related to any deleted question.

Comment: @fixer1234 - A question on hold and deleted by a moderator should be addressed on a case by case basis.  The moderators are normally in the chat room to discuss something like that.

Comment: @Ramhound - Each question, yes.  I'm referring to the messaging that the system automatically displays with all deleted questions.  If the message says to revise the question, and revising a deleted question is possible, there should be instructions on how to access the question to accomplish that.  If it isn't possible, the message shouldn't say to do it.  If revising a question requires moderator intervention, the message should say to contact a moderator in the chat room.  The system message should be consistent with reality.